# Getting duplicate Recept counters output from telnetlib python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an overridden output from telnetlib by accessing a device and i don't know how to resolve it to get correct output.

I tried the following code:

```
import re

import os
import sys
import time
import telnetlib

def telnet_dut():
    tn1 = telnetlib.Telnet('10.22.12.98')
    print(tn1)
    tn1.read_until(b"AB-OS login:")
    tn1.write('adm'.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn1.read_until(b"Password:")
    tn1.write('adm'.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn1.read_until(b"AB-OS")
    tn1.write('sh int gi 0/10'.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    output = str(tn1.read_until(b"AB-OS login:").decode('ascii'))
    file1 = open('PATH_TO_FILE/sample.txt' , 'w+')
    file1.write(output)
    file1.close()
    tn1.close()
```

Expected output:

> Recept Counters   Oct                    : 64
>
> Transmit Counters    Oct                    : 64

Actual output:

> Recept Counters^M^M    Oct                    : 64^M^M
>
> ^[[100B^M^[[K^M--More--^[[K^M Idle Timer expired, Timing Out !!! ^M
>
> Recept Counters^M^M
>
> Oct                    : 64^M
>
> ^M Transmit Counters^M    Oct                    : 64^M

Comment: May be [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That default pagination isn't doing you any favors.
Disable it, so you don't suffer timeouts while the router
waits for you to hit spacebar.

Replace:

```
    tn1.read_until(b"AB-OS")
```

with:

```
    tn1.read_until(b"AB-OS")
    tn1.write(b"set terminal length 0\n")
    tn1.read_until(b"AB-OS")
```